# How to get the behavior of `git diff master <commit>:<directory>` in Rust git2

Tags: rust, libgit2

I want to compare my local repository only with a sub-directory of my remote. Though native git command, I can achieve this by:
`git diff master <a remote commit>:>directory>`

How can I achieve this through Rust git2 crate?

Comment: In the C library it should be obvious from the name `git_diff_tree_to_tree`. Does the Rust wrapper pretend that only commits can be diffed or something?

Comment: Or are you confused about the `revparse` part?

Comment: I was confused how to achieve the tree for `<a remote commit>:>directory>`. But I think I can achieve that through walking the tree pointed at the given commit thanks

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned by @o11c, this is exposed in the C library by the `git_diff_tree_to_tree` function, which corresponds to [`Repository::diff_tree_to_tree`](https://docs.rs/git2/0.13.20/git2/struct.Repository.html#method.diff_tree_to_tree) in Rust.

`master` would be passed in the `old_tree` parameter, `<a remote commit>` in `new_tree`, and `<directory>` can be specified with the `opts` parameter, constructed using [`DiffOptions::pathspec`](https://docs.rs/git2/0.13.20/git2/struct.DiffOptions.html#method.pathspec).

Comment: I'm pretty sure `pathspec` is for `git diff tree1 tree2 some/dirs`, which is not what OP wants. The second argument needs to be the *tree*, which I think is looked up using `repo.revparse_single` and then unwrapped somehow.